# Can i release a new APK to a specific country?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an APK in production already, and in the pricing and distribution section of my google console, all of the countries are checked.

For my new release i would like to deploy this APK to one country only, is that possible?

If i change the country distribution in google console and leave only the country i want my release to be in, will this mean that my app will disappear from other countries markets?

Comment: ======**YES!**======

Comment: I don't believe you can release an *update* to only one country. The country settings are global for the app so if you remove all but say, US, users in Canada would no longer be able to download the existing version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
The application can not be downloaded with a device of another country.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the countries in which you want your application to be visible or downloadable. If you dont select some countries your app will not show up on their google play.